# User who was commenting to help clarify question has not followed chat invitation

Tags: discussion, support, comments, chat

I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795274/javascript-debugging-wrong-place-or-wrong-reference/37796041#37796041) and took a lot of time to make it a detailed and non-duplicate question.

Our discussion in the comment section expanded, and I was prompted to move to the chat. I did it as soon as I saw the notification. However, the person I had a discussion with never joined the chatroom.

As a result, we tried to have some additional discussion in the comment section, only to be constantly reminded to move to chat. In the end, the whole discussion was placed on hiatus, which is not what I want after I spent so much time writing it.

So, how exactly do we proceed from there? I am new to this chat feature, and I tried everything this site has to offer. I just don't want the question to remain unresolved because of my lack of feature knowledge.

Comment: that feature is just an optional one, it won't force any participants to chat and if they don't want to use chat they don't have to.

Comment: Some users hate chat. They wil never join the room when invited.

Comment: The question in Gooonnneeee..   ヾ(*ﾟ∇ﾟ*)ﾉ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The site doesn't work that way; chat is strictly optional. Users are never "moved into the chatroom." The user has to actually click the link in the comment that says, "Let us continue this discussion in chat." If the user doesn't want to do that for whatever reason, he or she can use the comments feature indefinitely.

In this case, the other user posted exactly one comment after you suggested moving to chat. You then posted a couple more comments. The other user never responded, but that doesn't mean "the whole question was placed on hiatus." Nothing was "placed on hiatus." The other user just hasn't responded.

Your question is really this part:

> So, how exactly do we proceed from there? I am new to this chat feature, and I tried everything this site has to offer, I just don't want the question to remain unresolved because of my lack of feature knowledge.

Here's your answer: **Be patient.** The last action was just an hour ago. Maybe the other user is on lunch break. Maybe he will come back. Maybe not. But there's no need to panic just yet.

In short,

[image]

Comment: I am sorry everyone, I am new to this website, and I wanted to try as many features as this website could offer. I was just afraid that me or the person I was having discussion with would be penalized in some way if we ignored warnings, that is why I asked here, just to make sure.

Comment: @VadzimSavenok No worries; it's better to ask if you're not sure about the rules!